# wrapping knockout.js using clojurescript

Tags: clojure, knockout.js, clojurescript

I'm trying to wrap knockout.js in clojurescript but its turning to be very difficult. The problem that I'm having is the reference to the 'this' variable. I'm thinking of giving up and just using javascript directly.

I've taken examples off http://knockoutjs.com/examples/helloWorld.html and http://knockoutjs.com/examples/contactsEditor.html

I've managed to wrap easy functions with some macros. For example:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
    this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");

    this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
        // Knockout tracks dependencies automatically. It knows that fullName depends on firstName and lastName, because these get called when evaluating fullName.
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    }, this);
};
```

becomes:

```
(defviewmodel data
  (observing :first_name "Bert")
  (observing :last_name  "Bertington")
  (computing :name [:first_name :last_name]
    (str :first_name " " :last_name)))
```

However, for something harder like:

```
var BetterListModel = function () {
    this.itemToAdd = ko.observable("");
    this.allItems = ko.observableArray(["Fries", "Eggs Benedict", "Ham", "Cheese"]); // Initial items
    this.selectedItems = ko.observableArray(["Ham"]);                                // Initial selection

    this.addItem = function () {
        if ((this.itemToAdd() != "") && (this.allItems.indexOf(this.itemToAdd()) < 0)) // Prevent blanks and duplicates
            this.allItems.push(this.itemToAdd());
        this.itemToAdd(""); // Clear the text box
    };

    this.removeSelected = function () {
        this.allItems.removeAll(this.selectedItems());
        this.selectedItems([]); // Clear selection
    };

    this.sortItems = function() {
        this.allItems.sort();
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new BetterListModel());
```

I'm not sure what I can do in clojurescript to match code like this: `this.allItems.push(this.itemToAdd())`

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you can hold tight for a month, we will be open sourcing the Knockout.js-inspired computed-observables library that we've been using internally at Keming Labs. Keep an eye on my Github (@lynaghk).

Comment: Thanks Kevin! I'm really looking forward to playing around with the library. However, there are just too many great javascript libraries out there that have similar types of problems of declaring variables that access other internal variables that clojure does not have. I feel that its important to have a clear way to interpolate between js and cljs. The more I play with clojurescript ande javascript, the more I find that good js libraries are in a lispy way... which I only saw the connection after learning clojure. Anyways, hope to get your comments on my answer below

Comment: Have a look on http://fluentsoftware.github.com/cljs-binding/ , not so mature as Knockout, but..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After lots of trial and error, I figured out how to have the same structure for clojurescript as for javascript.

The `this-as` macro has a few idiosyncrasies and only works when the method is put into the class

for example I want to create something that looks like this in javascript:

```
var anobj = {a: 9,
             get_a: function(){return this.a;}};
```

I have to do a whole lot more coding to get the same object in clojurescript:

```
(def anobj (js-obj))
(def get_a (fn [] (this-as me (.-a me))))
(aset anobj "a" 9)
(aset anobj "get_a" get_a)
```

which is seriously ugly for a language as beautiful as clojure. Things get worse when you have got functions that link to each other, like what happens in knockout.

I found that the best way to create an js-object with lots of `this`'s in there is to define a `__init__` method, add it to the class and then run it, then remove it from the class. For example, if I wanted to make another object:

```
var avobj = {a: this,
             b: 98,
             c: this.a
             get_a: function(){return str(this.a) + str(this.c);}};
```

written as clojurescript with and `__init__` method looks like this:

```
(def avobj (js-obj))
(def av__init__ 
     #(this-as this 
        (aset this "a" this) 
        (aset this "b" 9) 
        (aset this "c" (.-a this))
        (aset this "get_a" (fn [] (str (.-a this) (.-c this))))))
(aset avobj "__init__" av__init__)
(. avobj __init__)
(js-delete stuff "__init__")
```

There's still a whole bunch more code than javascript... but the most important thing is that you get the same object as javascript. Setting all the variables using this form also allows the use of macros to simplify. So now I have defined a macro:

```
(defmacro defvar [name & body]
   (list 'do
    (list 'def name
      (list 'map->js 
        {
          :__init__ 
          (list 'fn []
              (list 'this-as 'this
                 (list 'aset 'this "a" "blah")))          
        }))
    ;(. js/console log ~name)
    (list '. name '__init__)
    (list 'js-delete name "__init__")))
```

and with map->js taken from jayq.utils:

```
(defn map->js [m]
  (let [out (js-obj)]
    (doseq [[k v] m]
      (aset out (name k) v))
    out))
```

Now I can write code like this:

```
(defvar avobj
   a this 
   b 9 
   c (.-a this)
   get_a (fn [] (str (.-a this) (.-c this))))
```

and for the answer to knockout:

```
(defvar name_model
    first_name (observable "My")
    last_name (observable "Name")
    name (computed (fn [] (str (. this first_name) " " (. this last_name)))))

(. js/ko (applyBindings name_model));
```

Which is really nice for me as it matches javascript really well and its entirely readable!

Answer (score 2):

If you need an explicit reference to JavaScript's `this` dynamic binding, ClojureScript provides a `this-as` macro:

https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/master/src/clj/cljs/core.clj#L324